# How to enable image lazy load on homepage in Genesis theme framework

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, genesis, lazy-loading

I have install bj lazy load plugin but it is not working on the Genesis homepage featured images.

According to BJ lazy load plugin official documentation, we can add lazy load support to other images by using the code snippet provided below.

```
<?php
$img_html = '<img src="myimage.jpg" alt="">';
$img_html = apply_filters( 'bj_lazy_load_html', $img_html );
echo $img_html;
?>
```

But now I am confused on how to implement it in  Genesis framework.

**Edit**: I am trying to avoid those lazyload addons which require jQuery or similar libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://wordpress.org/plugins/a3-lazy-load/ and let me know it works for you or not.

Comment: I am actually looking for no dependency (like jquery ) only javascript solution.

Comment: Either close this topic about plugin and start another question or edit your question otherwise you might not get any answer. Check this link and it might work - https://alexmuraro.me/posts/lazy-load-all-images-in-wordpress/